# How to debug destruct function in Cpp program

Tags: c++, destructor

## Code

I am trying to debug below code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class wine
{
public:
    //wines name/brand
    char *name;
    //wines age
    int age;
    //in liters
    long double volume;
    //def construct
    wine();
    //construct
    wine(char *name, int age, long double volume) : name(name), age(age), volume(volume) {};
    //destruckt
    ~wine();
};

wine::wine() {}
wine::~wine() 
{
    delete &name;
    delete &age;
    delete &volume;
}

int main()
{
    char a[5] = { 'G','a','l','l','o' };
    wine old(a, 50, 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << a[i];
    }
    while (!std::cin.ignore());
    delete &old;
    return 1;
}
```

What I have observed while debugging is that the destruct function is the error but I have not achieved anything else

Comment: There is no effort in all at asking this question(?)

Comment: StackOverflow was rightly blocking your question because there's no problem statement in the question. What is not working? How is it not working? What did you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: You use `delete` for things allocated with `new` (only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do any dynamic memory allocation with `new`, so you need no `delete` either. Remove the `delete &old;`. The destructor will automatically be called when `old` goes out of scope (which is at the end of your `main` function).

> well what i have observed while debugin is that the destruct function
>   is the error

That's right. Your `wine` class contains nothing that is dynamically allocated and therefore nothing that needs to be deleted using `delete`. Yet your destructor tries to delete its member variables.

Remove those `delete` calls in the destructor. You can just get rid of the destructor as a whole if you want (this way `wine` is left with a default destructor that does nothing special).